# Should the 'squeeze' tag be kept or destroyed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are 56 questions tagged with the [squeeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squeeze) tag.  There is no tag wiki.  The majority of the questions seem to refer to Debian Squeeze, but there are a number of other meanings of squeeze represented.

Personally, I think it would probably be best to destroy the tag.

Failing that, it should be designated as a reference to Debian Squeeze (and a wiki entry created that says that is what it means), and the questions not needing that tag should be untagged.  I note that there is no tag for Debian Wheezy, which argues that maybe it isn't needed for Squeeze either.

There is a [debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debian) tag.  If I was going to create tags for versions of Debian, then they'd named like `debian-wheezy`, `debian-squeeze`, etc; then there'd be a need to retag from `squeeze` to `debian-sqeeze`, etc.

---

#### Update 1

There are now 39 questions related to Debian Squeeze with the [squeeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squeeze) tag.  I've edited in a basic 'do not use, but if you must, use it for Debian Squeeze' tag wiki.

#### Update 2

Every question tagged with [squeeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squeeze) is now also tagged [debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debian). Unless there's a humungous outcry all of a sudden, I plan to remove the [squeeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squeeze) tags from the remaining 40 questions (one got added overnight) — unless some other kind soul gets the job done before I get around to it.

#### Update 3

There was no outcry, so the [squeeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squeeze) tags have been squeezed out of existence. There are currently no questions tagged [squeeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squeeze).

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Am I missing something? The [squeeze] tag is still there and nothing seems to have changed since you [status-completed] this...

Comment: Sorry, was on the "featured" tab.

Comment: The word "squeeze" could refer to any number of technologies. To me it sounded like a compression algorithm. The tag should be converted to debian-squeeze because it is too unspecific.

Comment: @usr Could you put that comment in an answer?

Comment: Instead of destroying the tag how about if we annihilate it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As someone that used Debian squeeze, there are little to no situation where the fact I'm using it would affect the answer in a programming environment. I would say just burn it.

Answer (score 10):

The word "squeeze" could refer to any number of technologies. To me it sounded like a compression algorithm. The tag should be converted to `debian-squeeze` because it is too unspecific.

Comment: I would argue that [debian-squeeze] doesn't need to exist either. I can't think of any instances where would matter, and a cursory glance at the current [squeeze] questions doesn't provide any examples.

Comment: @Chris in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squeeze I find many questions that seem to depend on the fact that they refer to debian-squeeze. On the other hand I know nothing about it so they might just be general linux question. Also, many of them seem to be ripe for closing...

Comment: @usr from intuition and a quick glance over the first few questions, I'd say the tag shouldn't exist. People seem to either be using this tag as general information saying "I'm using this exact OS", which is pointless (it may be neccessary in an extremely limited number of cases but not with a frequency that we need a tag for it); or ask questions specific to the OS itself, e.g. how to install a package, which are off-topic for SO and should rather be asked on SuperUser or Unix.SE. Also, I doubt anybody will follow a tag for a specific OS version.

Answer (score 1):

Someone is already removing [squeeze] tags right now. Can such actions be blocked somehow? We had exactly the same scenario recently with another tag

Comment: Maybe a "PLEASE DON'T RETAG [link-to-meta]" in the tag wiki for the ones that haven't been figured out? It would be nice to have a real system for tag-burnation discussions.

Comment: I didn't do any tag editing until after this appeared ('twas not me), but I did remove some (maybe half-a-dozen or so) tags after this, as indicated in my update to the question.  The removed tags were not for Debian Squeeze.