# Burninate [linux-wheezy]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[linux-wheezy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-wheezy) looks like a pretty new tag, currently containing only <del>7</del>8 questions (most of which look pretty off-topic to me).

I don't think that it's serving any useful purpose, in fact it may be giving new users the false impression that their questions about setting up their Wheezy box are on topic for this site. Perhaps we should nip it in the bud.

Comment: Why is it called [linux-wheezy]? If it exists it should be called [debian-wheezy].

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254118/should-the-squeeze-tag-be-kept-or-destroyed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're entirely correct. Almost all of the questions which were tagged as [linux-wheezy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-wheezy) were out of scope for Stack Overflow, such as:

- [how to install wireless driver in debian (kali)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461070/how-to-install-wireless-driver-in-debian-kali)
- [BeagleBone Debian boot time (IPV6, ethernet..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099213/beaglebone-debian-boot-time-ipv6-ethernet)
- [Install R 3.1.2 on Wheezy 7.8 (Raspbian) fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309891/install-r-3-1-2-on-wheezy-7-8-raspbian-fails)

The few that were in scope weren't specifically about that release; most of them were about problems which only *incidentally* occurred on a Debian Wheezy system:

- [java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException when trying to get the mimetype of file by URL in production env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137728/java-lang-reflect-undeclaredthrowableexception-when-trying-to-get-the-mimetype-o)
- [meaning of “command” prefix and suffix of “!”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918601/meaning-of-command-prefix-and-suffix-of)

I have removed the tag from every question it was applied to, and retagged the questions as [debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debian) where that tag was not already present. The tag should be automatically deleted within a day or so.

I've also applied a similar treatment to [debian-7.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debian-7.6.0). Debian 7.6 was [a minor update to Wheezy](https://www.debian.org/News/2014/20140712); it's even less significant to developers than Wheezy was in general. As with the other tag, none of the questions under this tag were specific to the release.

Comment: "...and retagged the questions as debian where that tag was not already present" - I surely hope you only did that in cases where the problem was definitely specific to the OS. There's no use in tagging an OS to a question just because OP is using it.

Comment: @l4mpi Correct. You'll note that I didn't add the tag on the last two questions.